# Use values as new variables conditional on other variable

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I'm looking at a dataframe like this

```
marker <- c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5))
val <- c(1:10)

df <- data.frame(marker, val)
```

Which looks like this:

```
+-----+--------+------+
|     | marker |  val |
+-----+--------+------+
|  1  |    0   |    1 |
|  2  |    0   |    2 |
|  3  |    0   |    3 |
|  4  |    0   |    4 |
|  5  |    0   |    5 |
|  6  |    1   |    6 |
|  7  |    1   |    7 |
|  8  |    1   |    8 |
|  9  |    1   |    9 |
| 10  |    1   |   10 |
+-----+--------+------+
```

I would like to make a new column variable `yes`, which takes the value `val` if `marker` is 1 and a new column variable `no` which takes the value `val` if `marker` is 0. So I would like this:

```
+----+-----+----+
|    |  no | yes|
+----+-----+----+
| 1  |   1 |  6 |
| 2  |   2 |  7 |
| 3  |   3 |  8 |
| 4  |   4 |  9 |
| 5  |   5 | 10 |
+----+-----+----+
```

I suspect this could be done with `reshape2`'s `cast` function, but I can't wrap my head around it.

*Edit:* In light of the answers and concerning my real-life dataset::

- The first column is just the dataframe index, not it's own variable! Sorry for the confusion.
- The number of 0 and 1 in `marker` will not necessarily be in order or of the same number. `val` is just a value. Here I put 1 to 10, but those are just placeholders.

Comment: Could do something like `dcast(df, ave(marker, marker, FUN = seq) ~ ifelse(marker > 0, "yes", "no"))` (using reshape2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse` as follows,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(marker) %>% 
 mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
 spread(marker, val)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
#    new   `0`   `1`
#* <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     6
#2     2     2     7
#3     3     3     8
#4     4     4     9
#5     5     5    10
```

Comment: I actually don't need a column `new`, I just meant the dataframe's index. But in this way it actually also worked on my messy real-life dataset which many variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As long as each group has the same number of elements, you can use `split` and `data.frame` in base R. `setNames` adds the desired names.

```
setNames(data.frame(split(df$val, df$marker)), c("No", "Yes"))
  No Yes
1  1   6
2  2   7
3  3   8
4  4   9
5  5  10
```